# How to have my game fill the screen with the correct aspect ratio

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, scale, game-development

Hello and thank you for reading my post!
[What my game looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hpK8.png)

I've created a simple layout with a Canvas and a panel and a few buttons.  When I view the game in the In-Unity simulator, my project appears in the bottom left corner of different simulated phones.
Is there a way I can have my project fill the screen with the correct aspect ratio?

I tried coding the entire thing (every button and UI element independently) and I think there must be an easier solution here that I'm missing.  Please help me!

I played around with the Canvas Scaler component but it didn't help.
Also I tried out the Aspect Ratio Fitter but it says I can't use it because my Canvas has a fixed width and height.

Comment: Set your canvas scaler to "scale with width or height"

Comment: Look up the anchor system in Unity. Also, you should almost never put another Canvas as a child of a Canvas, it can break a lot of things. Use a panel instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set up your canvas scaler properly. In most cases, it is a good practice to use some reference resolution for mobile app. For example, 1080x1920 and make all positioning according to this.

You can find an explanation [in this video](https://youtu.be/be4gDI8RZ2U?t=250).